# Accessing Grails services from src/groovy

Tags: grails, dependency-injection

Grails services are abstractions used for implementing business logic (as well as connecting to backing services/DBs, etc.) outside of a controller. So in a typical controller you might have:

```
class DashboardController {
    StatisticsService statsService

    def index() {
        // Fetches all the stats that need to be displayed to the
        // admin on the dashboard.
        AdminDashboardMetrics adm = statsService.getAdminStats()

        render(view: "/dashboard", model: [ adm: adm ])
    }
}
```

Here, Grails automatically injects the `DashboardController` with a bean instance of `StatisticsService` (provided of course that the service was properly created with `grails create-service ...`).

But what happens when I need to access `StatisticsService` *outside* of a controller, and particularly, under **`src/groovy`**?

```
// src/groovy/com/example/me/myapp/FizzBuzzer.groovy
class FizzBuzzer {
    StatisticsService statsService

    FizzBuzzer(StatisticsService statsService) {
        super()

        this.statsService = statsService
    }

    def doSomething(MyData input) {
        MoreData result = statsService.calculate(input)

        // use 'result' somehow, etc....
    }
}
```

**How do I properly inject `FizzBuzzer` with the same `StatisticsService` instance ad what is passed into `DashboardController`?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject grails service in spring bean by defining injection login in resources.groovy under conf > spring

As I made an ExampleService and Example class in src/groovy

ExampleService

```
class ExampleService {

 def serviceMethod() {
    println "do something"
 }

}
```

Example Class under src/groovy

```
class Example {

ExampleService exampleService

 def doSomething() {
    def result = exampleService.serviceMethod()
 }
}
```

resources.groovy under conf>spring

```
beans = {

 ex(Example){ bean ->
    exampleService = ref('exampleService')
 }
}
```

so I can define **Example ex** as spring bean in grails-app and it will have ExampleService injected by itself.

Hope this helps. Thanks

Comment: What if Example is not, and cannot be a bean. In other words, it needs to be constructed on the fly in response to the task at hand, not preconfigured in XML or resources.groovy. When I try to define Example in resources.groovy, it seems the container tries to instantiate it for me, but that is not what I want.

I'm looking for how to inject a grails service into a plain old groovy object.

Answer (score 4):

You can also get a service using `grails.util.Holders`

Example:

For injecting MyService service class, use `Holders.applicationContext.getBean("myService")`

Where "myService" is the name of your service class in lower camel case.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving this is by using ServletContext-

```
ApplicationContext ctx = (ApplicationContext)ServletContextHolder.

getServletContext().getAttribute(GrailsApplicationAttributes.APPLICATION_CONTEXT)

statisticsService = (StatisticsService ) ctx.getBean("statisticsService ")
```

see this blog - http://www.grailsbrains.com/availing-grails-goodies-in-srcjava-or-srcgroovy/