# grails groovyPageRenderer injecting in file inside src/groovy

Tags: grails, gsp

I want to inject groovyPageRenderer in a src/groovy/GSPFormatter,
How can I do that without calling the new constructor?

EDIT

```
package gsprenderer
import spud.core.FormatterInterface
import grails.gsp.PageRenderer

class GSPFormatter implements FormatterInterface {

   PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('groovyPageRenderer')

   String compile(String content) {
      groovyPageRenderer.render(view: new ByteArrayOutputStream().write(content.bytes), null)
   }
}
```

is my code in src/groovy/GSPFormatter (basically with the default injection mechanism which doesn't work either)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, you are referring to `grails.gsp.PageRenderer` ... btw, I am using Grails 3.3.0

Here is a small (**tested**) example -

In application.yml

```
grails:
    spring:
        bean:
            packages:
                    - ovr
```

in scr/groovy/ovr

```
package ovr.renderer

import grails.gsp.PageRenderer
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class CustomRenderer {
    @Autowired
    PageRenderer pageRenderer

    def page(){
        pageRenderer.render(view: '/myrenderer', model: [hello: 'hello'])
    }

}
```

in controller

```
@Autowired
CustomRenderer customRenderer

def myPage(){
    render customRenderer.page()
}
```

in views/myrenderer.gsp

```
${hello}
```

Related post -

[Accessing Grails services from src/groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33316913/accessing-grails-services-from-src-groovy)

[How to inject Grails services into src/groovy classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427697/how-to-inject-grails-services-into-src-groovy-classes)

PS - if you describe your `bean` in `/conf/spring/resources.groovy` please escape the part in `application.yml` (given above)

Comment: what about grails version 2.5.6 (I forgot to mention it)

Comment: Similar concept. Use `@Component` and `@Autowired`

Comment: I tried almost any combination related in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427697/how-to-inject-grails-services-into-src-groovy-classes but with no luck inclduing the one here, any hints? (bean is null )

Comment: where did you find `grailsApplication` ?

Comment: put in your **Config.groovy** `grails.spring.bean.packages=['gsprenderer'] ` then use `@Autowired` and `@Component`. Also, put `@Autowired GrailsApplication grailsApplication` **or only** `@Autowired PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer` inside `GSPFormatter` class

Comment: btw, post your full `stacktrace` , need to know where the `null` pointer occurs.

Comment: Error 500: Internal Server Error
URI
/mycms2/spud/admin/pages/1041
Class
java.lang.NullPointerException
Message
Cannot invoke method render() on null object
Around line 12 of GSPFormatter.groovy
9: @Autowired
10:    PageRenderer groovyPageRenderer
11: String compile(String content) {
12:  return groovyPageRenderer.render(view: new ByteArrayOutputStream().write(content.bytes), null)
13: }
14:}

Comment: post your Config.groovy

Comment: what happen if you use `@Autowired PageRenderer pageRenderer`

Comment: Cannot invoke method render() on null object (bean pageRenderer is null)

Comment: what if I want to use CustomRenderer outside of a controller?

Comment: you have to use @Autowired

Answer (score -2):

It seems that you can not inject any bean inside a file in the src hierarchy.

I turn my orientation to dealing with a renderingtemplates engine (simple,...)

Question closed,

many thanks